# Finding about native token of a parachain

Tags: parachain, rpc, token, data-analytics

Is there a way to query whether a chain has a native token and what it is?

For instance can I query Moonbeam, to find that it's native token is GLMR(Glimmer). Similarly for the rest of the parachains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have this information in the chain-spec of the network, if you want to query it, you can use RPC queries for it.

Specifically the [system_properties RPC call](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#properties-chainproperties)

You can query it using CURL:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "system_properties", "params": []}' https://moonbeam.public.blastapi.io
```

And you will get the token symbol of the network, GLMR in this case.

```
{"SS58Prefix":1284,"tokenDecimals":18,"tokenSymbol":"GLMR"},"id":1
```

Or you can use JS code, with PolkadotJS library.

```
const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://moonbeam.public.blastapi.io');
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
const properties = await api.rpc.system.properties();
console.log(properties.toHuman());
```

And you got the token symbol:

```
{
  ss58Format: null,
  tokenDecimals: [ '18' ],
  tokenSymbol: [ 'GLMR' ],
  SS58Prefix: 1284
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Sidecar](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar)'s endpoint `runtime/spec`.
So you would need to :

- Install Sidecar locally
- Add an [.env](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/master/.env.local) file that points to one of [Moonbeam's public endpoints](https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/get-started/endpoints/), e.g. `wss://moonbeam.api.onfinality.io/public-ws` (unless you are running a parachain node yourself)
- Run Sidecar with your new `env profile` as shown in the [README](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar#configuration)
- Then you can access the endpoint from your browser `http://127.0.0.1:8080/runtime/spec`
- The result is again in JSON format

```
    {
  "at": {
    "height": "2316673",
    "hash": "0xafdd015b8b04c039d5e6753cf9363e57a9a65ac5127a62b525b57761fc14533e"
  },
  "authoringVersion": "3",
  "transactionVersion": "2",
  "implVersion": "0",
  "specName": "moonbeam",
  "specVersion": "1803",
  "chainType": {
    "live": null
  },
  "properties": {
    "ss58Format": null,
    "tokenDecimals": [
      "18"
    ],
    "tokenSymbol": [
      "GLMR"
    ],
    "SS58Prefix": "1284"
  }
}
```

Comment: Another interesting alternative is to use Sidecar, thanks @dominique